# Keeping output from ModelBuilder in projected coordinate system of input?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, modelbuilder

My model input is a point feature class with groups of points which need to be sorted according to their unit_id and then a Minimum_Bounding_Geometry tool run to generate a polygon for each unit_id which is then saved in a Feature Dataset.

This all works in the model attached except my input point layer is a projected UTM coordinate system. However the output polygons are not projected. The reason this matters is that I want to use the auto-generated shape_Area attribute value but for that value to be a sqm area, I believe I need it to be in a projected coordinate system.
[image: current model]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say your output polygons are going into a Feature Dataset.

As per the [**documentation**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/feature-datasets/an-overview-of-working-with-feature-datasets.htm):

> When creating a new feature dataset, you must define its spatial
>   reference. This includes its coordinate system—either geographic or a
>   specific projection—as well as coordinate units and tolerances for
>   x,y; z-; and m-values. All feature classes in the same feature dataset
>   must share a common coordinate system, and x,y coordinates of their
>   features should fall within a common spatial extent.

Try setting the coordinate system in your Feature Dataset to a projected coordinate system.